# How do I put y(a) and y(b) initial conditions in odeint(python) instead of y(0) and y'(0)?

Tags: python, differential-equations, odeint

I can't seem (from  [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html)) to figure out how to put arbitrary initial (y(a) and y(b)) conditions into odeint for solving a differential equation of order two (for example [y''+k(1+tanh(x))y=0])

does anyone know how?

Comment: `odeint` is an [initial value problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) solver.  It sounds like you want to solve a boundary value problem, so take a look at [`scipy.integrate.solve_bvp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that scipy.integrate.odeint solves nomerically for initial conditions at t=0 only, so you need to solve a boundary value problem, and the right commando to do it is in: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_bvp